# Pandas: Run the same function on multiple dataframes in a directory and convert them from .txt to .xlsx

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many .txt files with a varying number of columns. For each file, I want to subtract the 3rd from the right column from the 2nd to the right column. The 3rd from the right column has a different name for each file while the 2nd from the right column doesn't.

I wrote this, which works for one file at a time. I want to be able to apply this function to all .txt files in a given folder or a folder with sub-folders that have .txt files inside.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(r'C:\Users\me\Downloads\TestData.txt') 

df['Average - Background']  = df.iloc[ : , -2] - df.iloc[ : , -3]

df.to_excel('TestData.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
```

I tried this but I get OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'io.excel.txt.writer'" and ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'txt'

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\me\1Test' + '/*.txt')
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_table(f)
    df['Average - Background']  = df.iloc[ : , -2] - df.iloc[ : , -3]
    df.to_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
```

Comment: think you are trying to write n excel to a .txt file try replacing the f in the last line with 

f.replace('txt', 'xlsx')

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! Can you explain the difference between what I had initially and your suggestion?

Comment: in the orig code you where trying to write the excel file back to the orig name of the file (with the .txt ending), that's not necessarily bad, but in this specific case it seems .to_excel only excepts file names with correct excel endings